# Need help on RestTemplate postForObject() method

Tags: json, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I have to send JSON data from one service method to the other using `postForObject()` method.
I saw one example on `RestTemplate` on [this link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-use-spring-resttemplate-0).

`postForObject()` method has the following format:

```
User returns = rt.postForObject(uri, u, User.class, vars);
```

Or

```
User returns = rt.postForObject(uri, u, User.class);
```

I want to know that, after using `postForObject()` method,  if we implement the service method to accept the `User` object, how it will look like?

In my project, I have code like

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
String uri = "http://testcode.com/myapp/api/launchservices";
ServiceRequest request = new ServiceRequest();
request.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
....
```

I am getting error at this line:

```
ServiceRequest req = restTemplate.postForObject(uri, request, ServiceRequest.class);
```

while executing this, I am getting this error mesage:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:493)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:452)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:302)
```

my implementation method is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/launchservices", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public boolean launchServices(@PathVariable ServiceRequest request) {
    System.out.println("Request: "+request.toString());
    return true;
}
```

How to get rid of this? What will be the URI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got solution to this problem.

In this example,method postForObject returns an object of class "ServiceRequest"

```
ServiceRequest req = restTemplate.postForObject(uri, request, ServiceRequest.class);
```

So, the method that implements this service with the above **'uri'** should return an object of class **ServiceRequest**
All it needs is, slight modification in implementation method  as below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/launchservices", method = RequestMethod.POST,  headers = "Accept=application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ServiceRequest launchServices(@RequestBody ServiceRequest request) {
    System.out.println("Request: "+request.toString());
    return request;
}
```

Comment: Man you saved me a lot of time with this clean example. Well is a question answer think but I used it as an example. You saved me a lot of time thank you. I can not watch mundial match without stress .